# Jasmine unit test not getting success call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

When I called the mocking data in service the promises working for resolve. But i called the service in controller it is not calling the success call back.

code:

```
Service:
    getHistory: function(deviceId,historyDataCount){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get(historyDataCall+deviceId+"/"+historyDataCount).then(function successCallback(response){
           return deferred.resolve(response.data);
        }, function errorCallback (response) {
            deferred.reject(response);
            return response;
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    },
```

Unit test:

```
    service.getMachine(machineId);
    service.getHistory(deviceObj.deviceId,5);
    httpBackend.expect('GET', '/v1/machine/22')
       .respond(200,mock_SingleMachine);
    httpBackend.expect('GET', '/v1/devices/history/19442/5')
        .respond(200,mock_Machine_History);
    httpBackend.flush();
   scope.History();
```

Controller:
       $scope.History() {
             var deffered = $q.defer();
             backendServices.getHistory(deviceId,                                         historyDataCount).then(function successCallback(response) {
                     console.log(response);
                 }

```
         }
```

Here Not getting the scuccessCallback to check the response.

Comment: Try putting your `httpBackend.expect` statements above your service calls and keep the `httpBackend.flush()` method where it is - that might help.